# How to resolve compilation of GPU program that relies on OpenCV?

Tags: c, opencv, compilation, cuda

How to solve this compilation problem?

```
1>tmpxft_00001548_00000000-14_buildSURFDescriptorsGPU.ii
1>Compiling...
1>getMatchesGPU.cpp
1>utils.cpp
1>surf.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\inc\cutil_inline_runtime.h(61) : warning C4005: 'MIN' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(205) : see previous definition of 'MIN'
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\inc\cutil_inline_runtime.h(62) : warning C4005: 'MAX' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(209) : see previous definition of 'MAX'
1>.\main.cpp(290) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(290) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(290) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(290) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(291) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(291) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(291) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(291) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(325) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(325) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(325) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>.\main.cpp(325) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>ipoint.cpp
1>integral.cpp
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\inc\cutil_inline_runtime.h(61) : warning C4005: 'MIN' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(205) : see previous definition of 'MIN'
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\inc\cutil_inline_runtime.h(62) : warning C4005: 'MAX' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(209) : see previous definition of 'MAX'
1>helper_funcs.cpp
1>fasthessian.cpp
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\inc\cutil_inline_runtime.h(61) : warning C4005: 'MIN' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(205) : see previous definition of 'MIN'
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\inc\cutil_inline_runtime.h(62) : warning C4005: 'MAX' : macro redefinition
1>        C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv\cxtypes.h(209) : see previous definition of 'MAX'
1>.\fasthessian.cpp(176) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>Generating Code...
1>Compiling manifest to resources...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>Linking...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cxcore200d.lib'
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\SURFGPU-1.0.1\surf.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>surf - 1 error(s), 19 warning(s)
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure Visual Studio

Open VC++ Directories configuration: 
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories

Choose "Show directories for: Include files" 
Add "$openCVDir\include\opencv" 
Choose "Show directories for: Library files" 
Add "$openCVDir\lib" 
Choose "Show directories for: Source files" 
Add "$openCVDir\src\cv" 
Add "$openCVDir\src\cvaux" 
Add "$openCVDir\src\cxcore" 
Add "$openCVDir\src\highgui" 
Configure your Project

After you've created a project you'll need to add the OpenCV dependencies.

Open Project Properties: Project > %projectName% Properties... 
Open Linker Input properties: 
Configuration Properties > Linker > Input Open the "..." window to edit "Additional Dependencies" and on each line put: 
"cv210.lib" 
"cxcore210.lib" 
"highgui210.lib" 
And any other lib file necessary for your project Your project should now build. If you get any errors try restarting Visual Studio and then doing a clean Rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

SO is not a debugger, but this error report is basically telling you it can't open 'cxcore200d.lib'. That is your problem. There are also 19 warnings you might want to look at.